# ClosedXml export using NumberFormat returns wrong amount of digits

Tags: export-to-excel, number-formatting, closedxml

I am exporting some data containing money values to Excel using ClosedXml.

I have money values in € and $.
For both I set the cell value and also a numberformat. But when I use the NumberFormat Excel gave me, it leads to all the numbers having 5 digits instead of 2.

I got those numberformats using Excel, selecting an accounting number format with 2 digits, switched to custom and copied the code from there. This lead to these formats:

```
string EuroFormat = "_-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* \" - \"?? €_-;_-@_-";
string DollarFormat = "_-[$$-en-US]* #.##0,00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#.##0,00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* \" - \"??_ ;_-@_ ";
```

I use these to set the Numberformat like this:

```
worksheet.Cell(rowNumber, 8).Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat(DollarFormat);
```

When I only use the euro format I dont get issues, but as soon as I start using the dollar format, the values in Excel show up with 5 digits. In Excel it now shows the number format:

```
 _-[$$-en-US]* #.##0,00000_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#.##0,00000 ;_-[$$-en-US]* "-"?????_ ;_-@_
```

What is happening? Why does it change the amount of displayed digits?